# what is the use of static object of same class within a class as its data member?

Tags: java, static

I was reading a code snippet:

```
Class MyDAO{
     public static final MyDAO DAO = new MyDAO();
     public void loadData(){
         //Hibernate Code to do something
     }
 ...
}
```

So I'm amazed, and questions I'm facing right now is:

as `static` keyword denotes that a "member variable, or method, can be accessed without requiring an instantiation of the class to which it belongs". In simple terms, it means that you can call a method, even if you've never created the object to which it belongs.

What is the use of declaring a `data member` as `static` and instantiating a class then? is it a design pattern or what? and Most Importantly what is use of that? Any how when you say `Class.staticMember` how is the class loaded into the memory of `JVM`?

Comment: Here it is something that you have created an instance and never want to alter the address to which it is pointing to. Your variable once created is constant now. Though you can definitely change instance fields for that object ( not a constant in true sense ) .

Comment: Just curious, where did you find such a code snippet?

Comment: We'd need a lot more context to answer this question in a reasonable way. Most likely answer is that it's simply sub-optimal code, though.

Comment: @VendantTerkar Take a look at my solution below and let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used to implement **Singleton** pattern.

Comment: But constructor is public in my case.

Comment: @VedantTerkar It is a bad way(breaks oop) to implement the singleton pattern but it's stil used for the same purpose (get the instance).

Comment: @VedantTerkar : right, then I'm not sure this code has a purpose. Waiting for other answers as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Data member is to be declared when you want it to hold same value across all instances(shared between different object of the class)

Declaring static is not a design pattern, but it is a way to design your application.

Further to this if your member is only consumed by methods in class and it is not expected to  be accessed directly you can make it private static.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of providing the DAO object to the rest of the application as a global object. It is crude and ugly and makes testing hard, because it's difficult to provide a mock implementation of the DAO.

Static members are initialized at the time that the class is loaded. Classes are loaded lazily when they are first referenced. Other classes in the application can access this DAO without having to initialize it.

Code like this is why Dependency Injection frameworks (Spring, Guice, Hivemind, etc.) were created. This code makes the application depend on a specific implementation instead of on an abstraction, using dependency injection reduces coupling and increases testability by having the application depend on an abstraction and having the DI container be in charge of selecting the implementation and enforcing singleton scope.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the use of declaring a data member as static and instantiating a class then?

Having **a** data member being static does not give you any reason for not instantiating that class, because your class may still contain other non-static members.

- *So when do you not have to instantiate the class?*

When all your members are static such as a utility class. An example is the Math class in Java.

> Most Importantly what is use of that?

If you class contains non-static members, how do you expect those data to be accessed if you do not instantiate the class? Remember that your non-static members will not exist in memory if the class they belongs to is not instantiated.

> is it a design pattern or what?

It has no direct relation with design patterns. Generally, you declare a member as static when it is a behaviour or property ***of the class itself*** and not individual objects.

> Any how when you say Class.staticMember class is loaded into the memory of JVM.

I won't know exactly how Java memory works internally, but static members exist even before object instantiation which means variables declared as static are already created and loaded during runtime.

That also implies static members actually belongs to the class (not individual instance).

Comment: **Remarks:** Regarding your main question on `"what is the use of static object of same class within a class as it's data member?"` In order to answer you, we need to see more codes, including how `DAO` object is being used there.